# player teleporting into other levels

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame, levels

So I basically want to load another map once the player collides with a object, specifically a "Portal" in my game. Which is really making the player move onto other levels. I don't want to jumble up my code with a bunch of function like "go_to_level_9" or something so I'm planning to use a list or dictionary or something. So how to those game devs out there do that? Code for main.py is here: https://pastebin.com/rpddq1MP. The part with the portal stuff, walls and a few others:

```
    for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
        obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2,
                         tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)
        if tile_object.name == 'player':
            self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
        if tile_object.name == 'zombie':
            Mob(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
        if tile_object.name == '#':
            Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y,
                     tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
        if tile_object.name in ['health', 'shotgun']:
            Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)
        if tile_object.name == 'portal':
            self.map = TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, tile_object.type))
```

how do you do it? I'm currently using Tiled and pygame so I'm also using pytmx.

Edit: When I run the code, it just gives me an error about my other file, tilemap.py.

Error:
`File "D:\coding\my_coding_stuff\python\games\pygames\little rpg\tilemap.py", line 49, in apply return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft) AttributeError: 'TiledMap' object has no attribute 'rect'`

Tilemap.py:

```
import pygame as pg
import pytmx
from settings import *

def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

class Map:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.data.append(line.strip())

        self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
        self.tileheight = len(self.data)
        self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
        self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth,
                                            y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))

    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def apply_rect(self, rect):
        return rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.centerx + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.centery + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit scrolling to map size
        x = min(0, x)  # left
        y = min(0, y)  # top
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)  # right
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)  # bottom
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone for wasting your time, but I figured out I would just make new() take a extra parameter, map, and whenever player touches a portal, it will just load the map that's in the portal's type slot like this:

```
def new(self, map):
    # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.items = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.map = TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, map))
    self.map_img = self.map.make_map()
    self.map.rect = self.map_img.get_rect()
    for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
        obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2,
                         tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)
        if tile_object.name == 'player':
            self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
        if tile_object.name == 'zombie':
            Mob(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
        if tile_object.name == '#':
            Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y,
                     tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
        if tile_object.name in ['health', 'shotgun']:
            Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)
        if tile_object.name == 'portal':
            self.new(tile_object.type)
    self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
    self.draw_debug = False
    self.paused = False
    self.effects_sounds['level_start'].play()
```